# How to write query in postgresql? (relationship many-to-many)

Tags: postgresql

I'm still a newbie. 
I created db like this :

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS image_store_db;
CREATE DATABASE image_store_db;

\c image_store_db;

CREATE TABLE categories_images (
    categories_images_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    design_url VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE images (
    images_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    desc_short TEXT NOT NULL,
    desc_full TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ref_categories_images (
    categories_images_id integer REFERENCES categories_images (categories_images_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    images_id integer REFERENCES images (images_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT ref_categories_images_pkey PRIMARY KEY (images_id, categories_images_id)
);

INSERT INTO categories_images(title, image_url, design_url)
    VALUES ('SIMPLE TITLE TEST', '/TEST_URL.PNG', '/TEST_URL.PNG');

INSERT INTO images(title, rating, image_url, desc_short, desc_full)
    VALUES ('SIMPLE TITLE TEST', 4.5, '/TEST_URL.PNG', 'TEST_SHORT', 'TEST_FULL');
```

Pls, help. Teach me, how write a query : insert (for image in category) and select (image from category id) and etc ...
pls ...

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-populate.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-select.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes that `categories_images` is the table of categories and `images` is the table of images. The table and attribute names seem to suggest that the concept of many-to-many join is not all clear to you yet; I would have called the three tables `category`, `image` and `category_image_map`.

For `INSERT`: if your problem are the `serial` primary keys, use `INSERT ... RETURNING`.
You can insert into all three tables in a single statement:

```
WITH im(im_id) AS (
        INSERT INTO categories_images ...
           RETURNING categories_images_id
     ),
     cat(cat_id) AS (
        INSERT INTO images ...
           RETURNING images_id
     )
INSERT INTO ref_categories_images (categories_images_id, images_id)
   VALUES ((SELECT cat_id FROM cat), (SELECT im_id FROM im));
```

For the query, you just join the three tables:

```
SELECT ...
FROM categories_images c
     JOIN ref_categories_images r
        ON r.categories_images_id = c.categories_images_id
     JOIN images i
        ON r.images_id = i.images_id
```

and add a `WHERE` clause for your condition, for example

```
WHERE c.categories_images_id = 42
```

or

```
WHERE i.image_title = 'Mona Lisa'
```